# Authentication failed in error log while setting up fedex for magento in sandbox mode

Tags: magento, fedex

I am new to the fedex shipping method. I want to integrate fedex as a shipping method in my magento store.But there is a issue that the shipping method is not displaying during the checkout process.This question may seems redundant but i have searched a lot but i couldn't get this up and running.

The Problem is Fedex shipping method is not showing up during checkout process.In the error log its **Authentication Failed**.

What i did:

1. Got the developers test credentials from http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/index.html
2. I have a store of UK.I tried getting the account for both US and Global as well and UK domestic because i was told that for domestic shipping you need to select that particular country while generating the test key.I tried both.
3. I setup the Fedex in sandbox mode. I have rechecked the credentials and it is all fine which i have been provided by fedex.
4. I chekout with a test product but the fedex didn't show up in shipping method.

Some answers that i get from similar type of questions but didn't work for me:

1. Setting up the weight for the product.
2. Checking whether the weight unit is in pound rather than Kilogram.

According to the error log it seems that there is a problem with the credentials but I checked multiple time and i entered same as the fedex provided me with.

My queries are:

1. What may have been the issue?
2. As this is to get the shipping rate what shipping information does magento sends to the Fedex to calculate the rates?

Does anyone have faced and solved similar type of issue. I am facing this for few days and i have got nowhere, so can any one please help me with this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The initial set of keys that Fedex provides are TEST keys, so you have to make sure you are hitting the test server "https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/XXXXXX" with those credentials.

The other way around will fail also, by this I mean using TEST credentials pointing to Production server https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/XXXXXX